# How to extend a .js file with a .ts file

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a legacy codebase with a .js file that looks like this:

```js
// myFile.js
export const returnStuff = () => 'stuff';
```

Now I want to add functionality to this file, but this time I want to use TypeScript. I don't want to rewrite the legacy .js file, I only want to "extend" it with new functionality written in TypeScript:

```js
// myFile.ts
export const returnSomethingElse = (suffix: string): string => 'something else' + suffix;
```

I want myFile.ts to contain all the exports from myFile.js, and also this new export that is added.

Is this possible? If I try to do this I get the following error in files that require `returnStuff`:

`TS2305: Module '"path/to/myFile"' has no exported member 'returnStuff'`

I've looked at ambient contexts in TypeScript, but that doesn't seem to solve the problem since now I have to declare the types for myFile.js. I want to avoid this, since at that point I might as well rewrite myFile.js to TypeScript.

Comment: Does the name (other than extension) really have to be the same? If so, why?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The reason I want the names to be the same is so that I can import all of the exports from both files by just importing myFile: `import * from 'path/to/myFile'`

Comment: You can do that with the answer below, with different filenames. With the same filename I suspect you'll run into trouble. (But you can try it with `myFile.js` and `myFile.ts`, it *might* work. I probably wouldn't.)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create a new separate file that exports everything `myFile.js` and also some further exports defined in the file itself.

I suspect if the base filenames are the same, you'll struggle, but you can readily do this with a slightly different base name. For instance, you might rename `myFile.js` to `myOldFile.js` then write `myFile.ts` like this:

```typescript
export * from "./myOldFile.js";

export const returnSomethingElse = (suffix: string): string => 'something else' + suffix;
```

`export *` re-exports all of the named exports of a module. So anything that used to import `returnStuff` from `"myFile"` will continue to do so, it's just a re-export now instead of the original (which is harmless and doesn't introduce overhead).

Alternatively, since TypeScript is (mostly) a superset of JavaScript, you might just change `myFile.js` to `myFile.ts` and add your new things to it. You may get lots of warnings about "implicit `any`" and such (and sadly, there's no `@ts-ignore` for multiple lines [yet](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19573)), but...